# How to add a routing rule that only match "dport"?

Tags: iptables, ip-routing, iproute2, openwrt, rules

In my OpenWrt box, I want to route only a specific protocol(tcp:1888) to a tun interface only for one PC(192.168.28.2), so I do as following:

`ip rule add from 192.168.28.2 dport 1888 lookup 123`

`ip route add default via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 table 123`

But it does **NOT** work!

When I check the rule list with `ip rule`, I get:

> 0: from all lookup local
>
> 32765:   from 192.168.28.2 lookup 123
>
> 32766:   from all lookup main
>
> 32767:   from all lookup default

I guest that the dport SELECTOR doesn't take effect.

How should I do?

Thanks!!!

Solution:
With Nikita Kipriyanov's help, I got it, but the FORWARD chain of mangle table doesn't work, I used the PREROUTING instaed.

Would pls anyone explain why should I use PREROUTING instead of FORWARD of mangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a netfilter *mark* rule in the *FORWARD* chain of the *mangle* table. Then add a routing rule using that mark:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.28.2 -p tcp --dport 1888 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1/0x1
ip rule add fwmark 0x1/0x1 lookup 123
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have successed, but by using PREROUTING chain of the mangle. the FORWARD chain doesn't work. would you pls explain me why?

Comment: I was too lazy to evaluate which routing decision we must target. There are two in the packet path: the one after PREROUTING which decides FORWARD or INPUT, and the one after FORWARD or OUTPUT before POSTROUTING, which decides which output interface to egress. I targeted for second routing decision, while it happened we needed to correctly use first one. I updated the answer to reflect your comment.